# Can you disable constructor syntax for a type?

Tags: rust

Say I define my own type in a Rust library, like so:

```
struct Date {
    year: u16,
    month: u8,
    day: u8
}

impl Date {
    fn new(y: u16, m: u8, d: u8) -> Date {
        // Do some validation here first
        Date { year: y, month: m, day: d }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to **require** users to use the `Date::new` constructor? In other words, can I somehow prohibit users from creating their own `Date` struct using the following constructor:

```
let d = Date { 2017, 7, 10 };
```

I ask because it seems to be a detrimental flaw if you cannot force developers to run their arguments through a battery of validation before setting the members of a struct. (Although, maybe there is some other pattern that I should use in Rust, like validating data when they are used rather than when they are created; feel free to comment on that.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict the construction of struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588819/how-to-restrict-the-construction-of-struct)

Answer (score 37):

**TL;DR: The "default constructor" is disabled by default already.**

The `struct` syntax is only available to those who have access to *all* the fields of the `struct`.

As a result, it is only accessible in the same module, as per privacy rules, unless all fields are marked `pub` in which case it is accessible wherever the `struct` is.

Note that the same is true of *functions*, since `new` is not marked `pub` here, it's inaccessible to any module other than the current one.

Comment: Ah! Excellent. Thank you, sir!

Comment: @8bittree: No, it's an unless. Let me qualify it a bit more.

Comment: @8bittree: Great! Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: So, assuming the Date struct was public, how would I make sure user's were only able to make a `Date` using `Date::new`, but still be able to access the properties of `Date`?  Would I have to make a 'throw away' private field in `Date`,  i.e. `struct Date { private_field_just_so_i_cant_be_instantiated: bool, ... }`?  (go easy on me, I'm just learning Rust :)

Comment: @jrahhali: You have a choice between "getters" to expose the properties, or a private field which in Rust you'd start with an underscore `_` to avoid warnings of being unused. I personally would recommend getters, as private fields are better encapsulated, allowing to change the internal representation without breaking the interface.