# How to restrict the construction of struct?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to forbid creating an instances directly from member initialization?

e.g.

```
pub struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
}

impl Person {
    pub fn new(age: u8, name: String) -> Person {
        if age < 18 {
            panic!("Can not create instance");
        }
        Person { age, name }
    }
}
```

I can still use

```
Person {
    age: 6, 
    name: String::from("mike")
}
```

to create instance. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

#### Answer to question

You cannot create that struct from member initialization, because members are by default private and cannot be used directly. Only the immediate module and its submodules can access private fields, functions, ... (see [the book about visibility](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch07-02-controlling-visibility-with-pub.html#privacy-rules)).

Your example works, because your function is in that certain scope.

```rust
mod foo {
    pub struct Person {
        name: String,
        age: u8,
    }

    impl Person {
        pub fn new(age: u8, name: String) -> Person {
            if age < 18 {
                panic!("Can not create instance");
            }
            Person { age, name }
        }
    }
}

use foo::Person; // imagine foo is an external crate

fn main() {
    let p = Person {
        name: String::from("Peter"),
        age: 8,
    };
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=999e3bee01cfbbe9c51d272310916b0d))

```
error[E0451]: field `name` of struct `Person` is private
error[E0451]: field `age` of struct `Person` is private
```

---

#### Make it possible to create a struct from the outside

On the other hand, if you want to make it possible to create an instance by member initialization, use the `pub` keyword in front of **all** members.

```
pub struct Person {
    pub name: String,
    pub age: u8,
}
```

Please note, that you can "bypass" the constructs requirement of `age >= 18` with this, so use it wisely. If this is not desired, use a get method for the fields.

---

#### Make it possible to access the fields, but not creating a struct from the outside

***Please see [KittenOverflows answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70965787/1021920) for a different approach to this.***

--

Sometimes it's useful to let the user of your crate access the members directly, but you want to restrict the creation of an instance to your "constructors". Just add a private field.

```
pub struct Person {
    pub name: String,
    pub age: u8,
    _private: ()
}
```

Because you cannot access `_private`, you cannot create an instance of `Person` directly.

Also the `_private` field prevents creating a struct via the [update syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.45.0/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax), so this fails:

```
/// same code from above

fn main() {
    let p = Person::new(8, String::from("Peter"));
    let p2 = Person { age: 10, ..p };
}
```

```
error[E0451]: field `_private` of struct `foo::Person` is private
  --> src/main.rs:27:34
   |
27 |     let p2 = Person { age: 10, ..p };
   |                                  ^ field `_private` is private
```

Comment: Your suggestion of a private member is exactly what most people reading this will want.  The other answer you cite does not seem better in any way.

Comment: Annoyingly, clippy suggests that the private member method is an antipattern, preferring `#[non_exhaustive]`

Comment: Yes, and I'm somewhat okay with that. Use the `non_exhaustive` attribute for that, it is better suited for this.
The only difference is the update syntax, if you want that use `#[allow(clippy::manual_non_exhaustive)]` on the struct.

Comment: About the `_private` approach, I can still construct a Person with `let p = Person { age: 12, age: String::from("Foo"), _private: () };` if I'm in the same module. Does this only help with not allowing the update syntax? Or is this an old behavior, removed in the latest versions?

Are there other approach to doing this than `non_exhaustive` and separating module approach? (since `_private` isn't working within same module.

Answer (score 21):

For Rust >= 1.40.0, consider applying the [non_exhaustive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/type_system.html#the-non_exhaustive-attribute) attribute to your struct.

```rust
// Callers from outside my crate can't directly construct me
// or exhaustively match on my fields!
#[non_exhaustive]
pub struct Settings {
  pub smarf: i32,
  pub narf: i32,
}
```

More info in the 1.40.0 [release notes](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/12/19/Rust-1.40.0.html#non_exhaustive-structs-enums-and-variants).

Comment: Even as I believe an attribute would be cleaner, this feels like using a feature for its side-effect and not its primary use, which could send the wrong message to users of your API.

Comment: This may work across crate boundaries, but it doesn't help the more common case of keeping construction private to a single module (rather than an entire crate).  It's also, as @MatiasPequeno points out, kind of an opaque abuse of the attribute.