# How can I make all the fields of structs publicly readable while enforcing the use of a "new" constructor

Tags: struct, rust, public, serde

Many structs need to enforce the use of a constructor for object creation, but I want to have public read access to all of the fields.

I need to access several levels deep with `bish.bash.bosh.wibble.wobble` - `bish.get_bash().get_bosh().get_wibble().get_wobble()` is not somewhere I want to go, for readability and possibly performance reasons.

This horrible kludge is what I'm using:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo {
    pub bar: u8,
    pub baz: u16,
    dummy: bool,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new(bar: u8, baz: u16) -> Foo {
        Foo {bar, baz, dummy: true}
    }
}
```

This is obviously wasting a small amount of space, and `dummy` is causing inconvenience elsewhere.

How should I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict the construction of struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588819/how-to-restrict-the-construction-of-struct)

Comment: TL;Dr use `()` instead of `bool` because the unit type is a zero sized type (ZST)

Comment: @hellow Thanks, the question is not the same, but the final part of that answer is applicable.  Using `_private: ()` still requires me to deal with its existence during serialisation - but I can work around that in `serde`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @hellow I now have a working solution:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize}; // 1.0.115

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Foo {
    pub bar: u8,
    pub baz: u16,

    #[serde(skip)] 
    _private: (),
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new(bar: u8, baz: u16) -> Foo {
        Foo {bar, baz, _private: ()}
    }
}
```