# Why put "_dummy: ()" in a struct?

Tags: rust

In the [`chrono`](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/blob/main/src/lib.rs) crate I noticed this:

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct ParseWeekdayError {
    _dummy: (),
}
```

What's the purpose of this `_dummy` field?

Comment: Pretty sure its just to introduce a private field to prevent construction outside of the crate. See [How to restrict the construction of struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588819/how-to-restrict-the-construction-of-struct)