# Prevent direct initialization of type alias

Tags: rust

I'm currently learning rust and stumbled across a problem I'm not sure how to solve.

I want to have a type (called `Guess`), thats just a `i32` limited to a certain number range (between 1 and 100 in example below). My current solution is to use a type alias implementing a `new` function to enforce the number range. Still it can be created through normal initialization, without using `Guess::new()`, because there are no private fields like in a struct.

Can this be prevented?
Also a direct change of the value should be prevented too.

Code example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=deb0a1d5de494d9a4ca00f013ce60635)):

```rust
type Guess = i32;

trait G {
    fn new(val: i32) -> Guess;
}

impl G for Guess {
    fn new(val: i32) -> Guess {
        if val < 1 || val > 100 {
            panic!("Only guesses between 1 and 100 are allowed!");
        }
        val
    }
}

fn main() {
    let guess: Guess = 23; // should not be allowed
    let guess: Guess = Guess::new(42); // only this should be allowed
    println!("Guess this number: {}", guess);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable default constructor in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017183/disable-default-constructor-in-rust)

Comment: @pretzelhammer sadly not. This applies to structs with private fields, but this is not the case here.

Comment: Why can't you make `Guess` into a struct with a private `i32`?

Comment: @pretzelhammer One would always need to access the field. I'd find it much simpler, if the value could be accessed directly.

Comment: The [newtype idiom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html) is the way to go for making a `Guess` strongly typed. If un-checked construction and un-checked assignment isn't allowed, then you have to put it in some sort of wrapper like a *newtype* or a struct like pretzelhammer suggests.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for the suggestion about the newtype idiom, that improved the code. But it seems like what I want to achieve is currently not possible, how I would like it.

Answer (score 1):

A `type` *never* gives you any additional privacy/guarantees/invariants. What `type` defines is strictly an alias: "use this name as another name for this existing type". In your code as it is, `Guess` and `i32` can be used interchangeably.

In order to implement the range restriction you want, you **must** define a new type (not just a new name for an existing type) using `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, what you want to do is use the "newtype" pattern, which is basically wrapping your type into another:

```
struct Guess(i32);

impl Guess {
    fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        assert!(val >= 1 && val <= 100,
            "Only guesses between 1 and 100 are allowed!");
        Self(val)
    }
}

fn main() {
    //let guess: Guess = 23; // this is an error now
    let guess: Guess = Guess::new(42); // fine
    println!("Guess this number: {}", guess.0);
}
```

The main different is that users will need to use `guess.0`.

---

A few other improvements too:

- No need for a trait just to define methods.
- Using `Self` avoids repetitions of the typename.
- `assert!` for `if` + `panic!`.